# Facebook app question

Tags: facebook

Recently I just finished a simple Facebook Air application, and some of my friends already using that for testing purpose.

The situation is like this:
There are 10 users that currently authorized my application and used it, from those 10 users, my FB account only related to 5 of them (the other 5 are not directly registered as my friends in my fb account)

My question is:

How can I query all users of my application? including those who are not related to my account in facebook?

Is there any sample of code where I logged into fb using my App ID & App secret? then query all application's user and not bound to my fb account?

Thanks in advanced.
Bromo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know - nope. The only possible way is to track the authorized users manually (but in this case you won't know if the user has removed the authorization manually from the `Account -> Application settings` page).

Comment: As I said - as far as I know. I may be wrong, but I never see solutions for such problem.